# When installing SSL via cPanel, "...already has a website on the IP address *..." error message

Tags: ssl, cpanel

I submitted a CSR, got the certificate, uploaded it to the server, etc via cPanel. However when I attempt to install it, this message shows up:

[URL] already has a website on the IP address “*”, but you requested to add an SSL website for that domain onto the IP address “[IP HERE]”. A single domain may not have websites on more than one IP address.

I am in CPanel -> SSL/TLS -> Manage SSL Sites. I click "Browse Certificates", and select my certificate, and all fields auto-populate. Clicking "Install Certificate" at the bottom creates this error message.

I have tried a new browser (to clear browser cache). I tried re-keying the CSR and re-creating the SSL and re-uploading it. I called GoDaddy support twice, with nothing helpful. I removed and uninstalled the old SSL. I tried changing to another IP and updating the DNS. I  restarted the server. I am out of ideas.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: A complete tutorial step by step: https://snippetnuggets.com/howtos/webTipsAndTricks/miscellaneous/install-free-ssl-with-godaddy-hostinger-hostgator-zerossl-cpanel-padlock.html

Answer (score 0):

We figured this out so I wanted to share the solution in case it can help someone. It was because the account's IP was assigned as *. To fix it, go to WHM>>Account Functions>>Change Site's IP address and set the IP to the server's IP instead of *.